# Unable to reboot and/or shutdown?

Tags: shutdown

```
wait-for-state stop/waiting
*Using makefile-style concurrent boot in runlevel 6
Can't open /etc/init.d/.depend.stop: No such file or directory
```

I receive this message upon a reboot or shutdown attempt. Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is because `/etc/init.d/` has been corrupt, you should try

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/rc
```

Check CONCURRENCY appears like this or add:

> CONCURRENCY="none"

Alternatively you can use

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

Comment: In regards to where on the file? This is what appears in that portion: CONCURRENCY=makefile
test -s /etc/init.d/.depend.boot  || CONCURRENCY="none"
test -s /etc/init.d/.depend.start || CONCURRENCY="none"
test -s /etc/init.d/.depend.stop  || CONCURRENCY="none"
if test -e /etc/init.d/.legacy-bootordering ; then
 CONCURRENCY="shell"

Comment: I'm thinking about simply doing a fresh reinstall and reformatting the "/" partition instead if all else fails. Would that solve the problem?

Comment: You init.d should change CONCURRENCY=makefile to CONCURRENCY=nonei equal in "f test -e /etc/init.d/.legacy-bootordering ; then CONCURRENCY="none.

Reinstall solve the problem