# Cannot Shutdown or Reboot elementary OS

Tags: shutdown, asus

I cannot shutdown my elementary OS in my ASUS G56JR Notebook.
I am trying other solutions I have found here in StackExchange but no changes, I am using actual version LTS of elementary OS Freya.

Comment: what you have tried till now? Have you tried shutdown from terminal `sudo shutdown -h now ` and to reboot `sudo reboot`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to reboot and/or shutdown?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1866/unable-to-reboot-and-or-shutdown)

Comment: No Ravan, I have tried that solution.

Comment: I will try with sudo shutdown -h now

Comment: let me know the result @Alex =)

Comment: 'sudo shutdown -h now' command works for me! But it takes few minutes to shutdown it. is there other way to solve shutdown button? I would like to shutdown Elementary using UI button.

Comment: Finally to solve that problem I edited grub file: sudo  gedit /etc/default/grub and I set GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to "nomodeset". Finally sudo sudo update-grub and restart laptop

Comment: help me please .PC re-opening after 3 second shuts down. my pc model is hp. this happens after upgrade Loki . kernel version 4.4.0.36

Answer (score 4):

Finally the best way to solve this problem is installing Nvidia Graphics driver and choose Intel Graphics device in Nvidia X Server Panel. After reboot, now I can shutdown and reboot my laptop normally.

Comment: I have done this, but after it the computer hangs on boot. I had to start in `nomodeset` mode, and then removed all nvidia packages using `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`. After that I can shutdown and reboot normally, but I am not sure still which graphic car I am using.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with my ASUS GL552VW. Fixed with a simple kernel parameter change.

1) Install **Grub Customizer**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

2) Open Grub Customizer and Edit the grub entry (with the Pencil Icon) 
[image: Grub Customizer]

3) Now make the desired changes. In this case,[image: Edit Menu]

you need to add a parameter on the second last line that starts with `linux /boot/vmlinuz-xxx....` add `acpi=force` before `ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff`
Click OK and Save. Now hard reset your laptop. It should be fixed from the next boot.

I'm using these parameters to boot and this fixes all the function keys operations, keyboard backlight, graphics and the shutdown problem.

`linux  /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=7e43add9-fbc2-4946-a640-0b269d17c117 i915.modeset=0 nouveau.modeset=1 nvidia.modeset=1 idle=nomwait acpi=force acpi_osi=! acpi_backlight=native ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff`

Answer (score -1):

Hit the same problem several times while trying to install elementary OS for the first time and fiddling to get window size other than VGA -- Mac OS host with Virtualbox -- and the advice above did work for me:

from Terminal

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

and to reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Once I got the installation and updates and window size fix working, the normal shutdown and restart pulldown menus work fine.

I did hang the VM once since then, by trying to change Files view from Icons to List -- had to power cycle again because terminal/mouse/keyboard weren't live.