# Freya - suspend not working (As computer would freeze)

Tags: release-freya, suspend

When I press suspend from menu. I only get black screen but I can hear disk running. *note: I've chosen encryption during installation - the whole disk as home * I've then install pm-utils and when I write sudo pm-suspsend computer freezes literally. I can't move mouse and when I try to wake it by pressing enter, it's not working.

I don't know how can I provide logs since then I'm forced to cold power off computer.

I can tell you hardware/software info:

hw: Acer Aspire v3 112p

CPU: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3540  @ 2.16GHz
GPU is intel's integrated, lspci | grep VGA says: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView Gen7 (rev 0e)

uname -a

> Linux rozica 3.19.0-31-generic #36~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 10:21:08 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Nope I'm not using ubuntu. I'm using lates Freya. Clean install month ago. Freya uses ubuntu's kernel. Check it yourself.

Comment: Just for non belivers:  No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary OS
Description: elementary OS Freya
Release: 0.3.1
Codename: freya

Comment: please run `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty` and let me know the result.

Comment: Can you please explain me why would older kernel fix the problem. As I mentioned, I currently have 3.19.0-31-generic kernel, but with your suggestion I would actually get older kernel:                                                                       `The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-generic linux-generic-lts-trusty linux-headers-3.13.0-67
  linux-headers-3.13.0-67-generic linux-headers-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-67-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-67-generic
  linux-image-generic xserver-xorg-lts-trusty`

Comment: reference [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/2wt5fl/acer_aspire_e11_e3112mc8ld_elementary_os_freya/)

Comment: @ravan that post was 8months ago... I can install those kernels but what if I break system, How do I revert back kernel?

Comment: I realised that 20 rep after posting comment---I am just executing the command--I don't think system will break (but having that doubt is good and need to clarified)

Comment: System not broken---still working =)

Comment: I've tried with 3.13 kernel as you suggeted (I chose kernel at boot) but problem persist. Can't suspend, can't reboot can't poweroff.

Comment: This Might Help You with the Problem: [shutdown/reboot issue fix](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/7662/6199)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a kernel issue because I tested several versions. I solved the suspend/resume issue by installing a proprietary video driver and blacklisting: nouveau

Comment: what proprietary  video drivers did you install? I have  Intel Corporation ValleyView Gen7 (rev 0e) video card. If you have intel video card too can you provide direct link for proprietary drivers pretty please? Or package name (even better).

Answer (score -1):

There are 4 suspending modes i am aware off that you can select in the BIOS/UEFI (S1-S4).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#OSPM_responsibilities

Make sure you select the one you need.